# inserting radio button in php page

Tags: php

I have retrieved the database details from a database to a
php page. i have actually retrieved a specific column of a query.
but i am not able to add the radio buttons to the retrieved values.
Following is my coding:

```
<?php
    $query  = "SELECT url FROM measurementurl";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $url  = $row[0];
        echo "url :$url <br>" ;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting radio button in php page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027828/inserting-radio-button-in-php-page) please in the future, do not start duplicates, but edit your original question. In this case though, it's better to stick with this one

Comment: Well, do you know the HTML syntax for a radio button? Currently you are only echoing plain text (and a "line break").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form action="">
<?php
    $query  = "SELECT url FROM measurementurl";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        //$url  = $row[0]; removed cause not used in code
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"url\" value=\"$row[0]\" />$row[0]<br />";
    } 
?> 
</form>
```

Comment: `$url = $row[0];` does not seem to have any use.

Comment: ups. you are right. I just copy paste from the original forget to make some cleaning. Thank you

Comment: thankyou !!!!!radio buttons are getting added but the urlid is not getting entered into my database.

Comment: ehay do you mean of `urlid is not getting entered into my database`?

Comment: sorry that was a silly mistake of mine.i have another doubt regarding entering checkbox values into the database.I have a php form with some text box, list of radio buttons and checkboxes with a submit button. I want to enter the values inputted in this php form to a database.The textbox as well as the radiobutton values and only one of my checkbox values are geting entered.I have a single column for entering the checkbox values in my query.I would like to know the syntax for entering all the selected checkbox values into that single column separated by commas.

Comment: @user621183 because that was a new question, why not you write a new question for that and let see if you can got answer for it.